# how to make pagination with so that there is less code in the fragment without paging 3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, pagination, listadapter

I parse NewsApi and use clean architecture also ListAdapter.
I need to do "pagination" so that In my fragment be less code.
By use abstract class or extension file, but I don't know, how to do it.
Also I don't understand how to do addAll method in ListAdapter, so that past items don't disappear.
How I understand paging 3 not compatible with clean architecture.

I have tried do the follow:https://coderoad.ru/51433106/kotlin-RecyclerView-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86
but it failed.

Also the follow:

```
fun pagination(viewModel: EverythingViewModel): RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
return object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
  override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
      super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

      if (dy > 0) {
          val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
          val firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
          val visibleItemCount = layoutManager.childCount
          val totalItemCount = layoutManager.itemCount
          if (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition >= totalItemCount) {
              viewModel.page++
              viewModel.getEverything()
          }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Also failed

If you need more details write me in the comments

Comment: You should not tag your question with "java" when it is related to Kotlin.

Comment: ok, I understood

Answer (score 0):

Here is the original post https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/pagination-in-recyclerview-without-paging-library-1c48e9328f81 . Basically author uses custon onScrollListener but I updated the code to avoid some bugs.

```
abstract class RecyclerViewPaginator : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

private var currentPage = 1
private var endWithAuto = false


abstract var isLastPage: Boolean



override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
    val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager
    val visibleItemCount = layoutManager!!.childCount
    val totalItemCount = layoutManager.itemCount

    val lastVisiblePosition: Int = when (layoutManager) {
        is GridLayoutManager -> layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
        else -> (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition()
    }

    if (isLastPage) {
        return
    }


    if (visibleItemCount + lastVisiblePosition >= totalItemCount) {
        if (!endWithAuto) {
            endWithAuto = true
            loadMore(++currentPage)
        }
    }
    else {
        endWithAuto = false
    }
}

abstract fun loadMore(start: Int)}
```

Please note that if you use it inside a fragment you should create instance onAttach (solved my navigation bug). You can properly define a function that fetches values in a viewModel. Then subscribe to livedata inside your fragment.